# Adding Tags work on create page, but wont work on edit page angular

Tags: angularjs, tags, angularjs-scope, meanjs

I'm trying to build an app with meanjs so most of it uses angular.  The idea is for the user to be able to add tags and delete tags to a certain post.  Add and deleting works great on the create page but once I try to add or delete on the edit post page it doesn't work anymore.

below is the html

```
<section data-ng-controller="ProductsController" data-ng-init="findOne()">
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Edit Product</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="update()" novalidate>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="product.name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
            <div class="tag-input-ctn">
                <div data-ng-repeat="(key, tag) in product.tags" class="input-tag">
                            {{ tag.name }}
                            <div class="delete-tag" data-ng-click="deleteTag(key)">&times;</div>
                        </div>

                        <input type="text" data-tag-input="" data-ng-model="newTag" data-ng-style="{width: inputWidth}" data-new-tag="addTag()" data-delete-tag="deleteTag()">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div ng-click="update()" value="Update" class="btn btn-default">update</div>
            </div>
            <div data-ng-show="error" class="text-danger">
                <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

below is the controller

```
angular.module('products').controller('ProductsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Products',
function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Products) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;

    $scope.tags = [];
    $scope.addTag = function() {
        if ($scope.newTag.length === 0) {
            return;
        } 

        $scope.tags.push({name: $scope.newTag});
        console.log('addTag ran');
        $scope.newTag = '';
    };

    $scope.deleteTag = function(key) {
        if ($scope.tags.length > 0 &&
            $scope.newTag.length === 0 &&
            key === undefined) {
            $scope.tags.pop();
        } else if (key !== undefined) {
            $scope.tags.splice(key, 1);
            console.log('tagspops');
        }
    };
```

I can see the logs when I enter the tags and click on x's, but nothing actually happens on the page, yet everything works fine if I'm only creating the post.

Please help me THANKSSS

Comment: It would be good if you could provide a full working example, that shows what you are trying to do. By full i mean something i can paste into a html document and run it.

Comment: Create and edit view both uses the same product controller. The above html is for edit

Comment: Ok, i should have said minimal example.. But lets help you a little bit with that:
Your js code has syntax errors(missing brackets)
The `ProductsController` defines a bunch of dependencies, without them the code will not run. 
In the html there are many functions (`update()`, `findOne()` which are not defined, so remove them.
In the model of the "name input" is `product.name`, where should `$scope.product` come from?
On the "tag input" there are the directives `data-new-tag` and `data-delete-tag`, are they defined anywhere?
So please provide an example that exactly shows your problem.